# Store procedure not getting executed

Tags: stored-procedures

Guys I have stored procedure which gets some values from linked server and update in another table

```
Declare @mno varchar(50)
Declare @trackid varchar (50)
If @mno =null
Begin 
Select top 1 mno from table order by mno desc
End 
If@trackid=null
Begin
Select top 1 trackid from table order by mno desc
End 
Update table set name=(select user from [192.168.2.6].[mydb].[dbo].[mytable] where mno =@mno), Sid=(select Sid from  )192.168.2.6].[mydb].[dbo].[mytable] where sid =@trackid
```

Based on top value in table it pics name and sid from linked server and update in table. When I execute this procedure it says executed successfully but table doesn't get updated. And when I execute update query manually it works correctly.

Please guide

Answer (score 0):

You're doing your SELECTs to get the mno and trackid, but you aren't actually assigning them to your variables.  Also, there's no reason to check if your variables are going to be null - you just created them on the line above, so you know they're ALWAYS going to be null.

```
Declare @mno varchar(50)
Declare @trackid varchar (50)
Set @mno = Select top 1 mno from table order by mno desc
Set @trackid = Select top 1 trackid from table order by mno desc

Update table set name=(select user from [192.168.2.6].[mydb].[dbo].[mytable] where mno =@mno), Sid=(select Sid from  )192.168.2.6].[mydb].[dbo].[mytable] where sid =@trackid
```